# Dropdown menu acting weird in IE 9

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

We have made a dropdown menu for our website and we just have to try it out in different browsers. The dropdown menu works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer 9
it acts weird. Here's the problem: Whenever you hover inbetween the space between li's the primary dropdown list shows up. Here's the html code.

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="mainLi"><a href ="matte/matte.html"> Matematik </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="matte/geometri.html">Geometri</a></li>
                <li><a href="matte/algebra.html">Algebra</a></li>
                <li><a href="matte/statistik.html">Statistik</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainLi"><a href ="csharp/csharp.html"> C# </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="csharp/variabler.html">Variabler</a></li>
                <li><a href="csarp/villkor.html">Villkor</a></li>
                <li><a href="csharp/upprepning.html">Upprepning</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainLi"><a href ="html/html.html"> HTML </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="taggar.html">Taggar</a></li>
                <li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.mainLi {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

nav ul li {

        border-right: 0px solid black;
        border-left: 0px solid black;
        float: left;
    }

nav ul ul  {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul  {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 0.5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul ul li  {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 100%;
}

nav ul li a  {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    display: block;
}

nav > ul > li:hover {
    background: rgb(183,208,226); /* Old browsers */
}
```

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/K5JGE/

Comment: please make a jsfiddle, possibly nobody will copy the codes to test it

Comment: @Seer i've added a JSFiddle for OP ... a quick glance shows it doesnt work in Chrome either, and is most likely due to incorrect child selectors

Comment: but I can't see any working dropdown menu

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/K5JGE/3/).

**The HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="mainLi"><a href ="matte/matte.html"> Matematik </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="matte/geometri.html">Geometri</a></li>
                <li><a href="matte/algebra.html">Algebra</a></li>
                <li><a href="matte/statistik.html">Statistik</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainLi"><a href ="csharp/csharp.html"> C# </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="csharp/variabler.html">Variabler</a></li>
                <li><a href="csarp/villkor.html">Villkor</a></li>
                <li><a href="csharp/upprepning.html">Upprepning</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mainLi"><a href ="html/html.html"> HTML </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="taggar.html">Taggar</a></li>
                <li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.mainLi {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

nav ul li {

        border-right: 0px solid black;
        border-left: 0px solid black;
        float: left;
    position:relative;
    }

nav ul ul  {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul  {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 0.5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul ul li  {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 100%;
}

nav ul li a  {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    display: block;
}

nav > ul > li:hover {
    background: rgb(183,208,226); /* Old browsers */
}
```

You just needed to `position` the child elements accordingly. Thats it.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the solution, you can add a green tick and accept with an upvote. If not, let me know in case of queries - @Lucas Perrera

Comment: thanks for your time but this didn't solve the problem for me. :S

Answer (score 2):

Also if you take the nav ul ul top:100%; off, it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

That one is working for sure @Nathan Lee.

Aswell you can use this "Template" or whatever you want to call it and make it to your own.
Well, that's what I always do!

[DropDownMenu](http://www.handy-html.com/create-a-simple-css-dropdown-menu/)

It's what I use from PSDCenter. (from George Orsmond)

Hope this works good for you too!

Comment: No problem, always glad to help. And to make the question awnsered, push the tick so people know it is awnsered :)

Comment: I cant push the tick, as I have not asked the question at this moment, shall surely do if I question and get the most appropriate answer for the same. - @Ryan de Vries

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` in `nav ul li`.